# Run JS function after form validates on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, flask, xmlhttprequest

I have 2 JS functions; the first `function1` sends info to the server to a python script once a button is clicked on the form. The second function, `function2` turns to the next page layer (NOT the next HTML page, this is a multi-page form all on one HTML page).

At the moment, I am using an onClick function on my button: `onClick="function1();"`, and JQuery. If one of the three entries is left empty, the form checks and tells the user to fill out the empty fields.

How do I make `function2` wait for `function1` to execute successfully, with all valid form entries and no errors with the python script (the python script returns '', 204 so there is no change to the page once that runs, so it's not that important to this question).

Below are my scripts of JS functions; any advice is appreciated.

```
<script>
  form = document.getElementById("formID");

  function function1() {
    form.action = "/runPythonFunc";
    form.submit();
    // JQuery validates the form to make sure all entries are filled
    // How do I make function2 wait now until all the entries have been filled by the user?
    function2('page2')
  }
</script>



<script language="JavaScript">
  var currentLayer = 'page1';

  function function2(lyr) {
    hideLayer(currentLayer);
    document.getElementById(lyr)
      .style.visibility = 'visible';
    currentLayer = lyr;
  }

  function hideLayer(lyr) {
    document.getElementById(lyr).
    style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

  function showValues(form) {
    var values = '';
    var len = form.length - 1;
    //Leave off Submit Button
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (form[i].id.indexOf("C") != -1 ||
        form[i].id.indexOf("B") != -1)
        //Skip Continue and Back Buttons
        continue;
      values += form[i].id;
      values += ': ';
      values += form[i].value;
      values += '\n';
    }
    alert(values);
  }
</script>
```

UPDATE:

I've been trying to work with AJAX, and have a couple different methods I've been working with, neither of which have worked yet. The specifics of each method are mentioned as comments in the code below:

First way

```
<script>
   function function1() {

    $.ajax({
      url: '/runPythonFunc',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        email: $('#User-Email').val(),
        entryTwo: $('#EntryTwo').val(),
        entryThree: $('#EntryThree').val()
      },
      success: function2('page2') { // getting error in this line "Syntax error: unexpected token '{'"
        return '', 204;
      }
    });
  }
  // Getting the error:     Uncaught ReferenceError: metaSQL is not define at HTMLInputElement.onclick
</script>
```

The above first way is giving these errors in dev tools (for clarification, `metaSQL is my` function1`, and` species1` is the ID for the entry on page 2 of the form (something we're not dealing with in this question)

[image]

Second way

```
<script>
  function function1() {

    return $.ajax({
      url: '/runPythonFunc',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        email: $('#User-Email').val(),
        entryTwo: $('#EntryTwo').val(),
        entryThree: $('#EntryThree').val()
      }
    });
  }

  function1().then(response => function2('page2'));  // not sure what to replace 'response ' with
  // Getting the error:     Uncaught ReferenceError: metaSQL is not define at HTMLInputElement.onclick
  // Also the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, and Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
</script>
```

Is there an ideal way between the two options above, or an entirely different way to use AJAX in my case?

Additional code, HTML form:

```
<form id="wf-form-Email-Form" name="wf-form-Email-Form" data-name="Email Form" method="post" action="">

  <!-- PAGE 1 -->
  <div id="page1" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">

    <!-- USER EMAIL -->

    <label for="Algorithm-Name-3" class="custom-question algorithm-name">Enter your email<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="User-Email" data-name="User Email" placeholder="Email address"
      id="User-Email" required="">

    <!-- ALGORITHM NAME -->

    <label for="Algorithm-Name-3" class="custom-question algorithm-name">What will you name your algorithm?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Name" data-name="Algorithm Name"
      placeholder="Be as creative as you like!" id="Algorithm-Name" required="">

    <!-- ALGORITHM DESCRIPTION -->

    <label for="Algorithm-Desc-3" class="custom-question algorithm-desc">Briefly describe what your algorithm does?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Description"
      data-name="Algorithm Description" placeholder="You can still be creative!" id="Algorithm-Desc" required="">


    <br><br>
    
<!-- NOTE: metaSQL IS FUNCTION1 -->
    <p><input type="submit" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="C1" value="Add Animal" onClick="metaSQL();"></p>

  </div>

  <!-- PAGE 2 (1st ANIMAL) -->

  <div id="page2" class="page">

    <p style="font-family: Poppins,sans-serif; color: #fff;">1st Animal</p>

    <!-- 1ST ANIMAL NAME -->

    <label for="Enter-species" class="custom-question enter-species" id="one_name">What animal are you looking for?</label>
    <row>
      <p> <input type="text" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="species1" placeholder="Enter name of animal" id="Enter-species" required="">
        <input type="button" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="S1" value="Search" onClick="animalSQL()">
        <div class="hidden-load" id="hidden-load">
          <lottie-player src="https://assets1.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_xs6VVO.json" background="transparent" speed="0.7" style="width: 80px; height: 80px;" loop autoplay></lottie-player>
        </div>
      </p>
    </row>

    <!-- NOTE: showLayer IS FUNCTION2 -->
    <p><input type="button" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="B1" value="Go Back" onClick="showLayer('page1')">
      <input type="button" class="submit-button-2 w-button add-another-animal" id="C2" value="Add another animal" onClick="animalSQL(); showLayer('page3')">
      <input type="button" class="submit-button-2 w-button finish_and_submit" id="F1" value="Finish & Submit" onClick="submitButton(), showLayer('page22')">
    </p>

  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

Cheers

Additional information (devtool screenshot) as requested by @Alwaysa learner, and python code (using Flask framework) below. To avoid confusion, `meta2sql` is the same as `

[image]

```
@app.route('/runPythonFunc', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def runPythonFunc():
    #function does work
    return '', 204
```

Comment: After these 2 lines `form.action = "/runPythonFunc"; form.submit();` page is no more processing any client side code. It is as good as clicking a link to page '/runPythonFunc'. Now if you like to call function2() based on the response on the form submitted, you need to write the code at page load and look for response from server and then take action. However, best approach would be to use ajax function and on success check the response from server and decide if to call function2 or show error message

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @AlwaysaLearner, what kind of response should I be looking for on the server side (python function)? I've been trying to use AJAX for the last few hours as well, and am currently updating the original post with what I've been working on, but can't get functioning right yet.

Comment: In your first way try this `success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {  console.log(data)}` instead of what you have for success and post what do you see inside devtools

Comment: Still getting the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: function1 is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: please include html codes for the form

Comment: Just added more info (devtools screenshot and html form) to original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go one step at a time.... Remove everything besides div with id page1 and run ajax on button click (Remove `onClick="metaSQL();` from button as well). Then post the result you get from console.log(data).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#C1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/runPythonFunc',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    email: $('#User-Email').val(),
                    entryTwo: $('#Algorithm-Name').val(),
                    entryThree: $('#Algorithm-Desc').val()
                },
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) { 
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>




<div id="page1" class="page" style="visibility:visible;">    
    <!-- USER EMAIL -->    
    <label for="Algorithm-Name-3" class="custom-question algorithm-name">Enter your email<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="User-Email" data-name="User Email" placeholder="Email address"                                                                                                               id="User-Email" required="">    
    <!-- ALGORITHM NAME -->    
    <label for="Algorithm-Name-3" class="custom-question algorithm-name">What will you name your algorithm?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Name" data-name="Algorithm Name"                                                                                                                                   placeholder="Be as creative as you like!" id="Algorithm-Name" required="">    
    <!-- ALGORITHM DESCRIPTION -->    
    <label for="Algorithm-Desc-3" class="custom-question algorithm-desc">Briefly describe what your algorithm does?<br></label><input type="text" class="text-field enter-name w-input" maxlength="256" name="Algorithm-Description"                                                                                                                                           data-name="Algorithm Description" placeholder="You can still be creative!" id="Algorithm-Desc" required="">   
    <br><br>    
    <p><input type="submit" class="submit-button-2 w-button" id="C1" value="Add Animal" onClick="metaSQL();"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just stripped everything down, and unfortunately the button is unresponsive when clicked (with entries filled or empty). Currently I'm only seeing `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in the devtools. Trying to figure it out at the moment. My code looks exactly like yours, except the <script> is below the html, I've removed `onClick`, and I've swapped in the real url python function that runs for `/runPythonFunc`

Comment: Seems like you are not importing jquery library. Have you included this line? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh! I must have had a different but similar line because I had that before but was getting a very odd security error. Your line fixed that! I'm adding a screenshot (to the original post) of the new message on devtools when I click 'Add animal' with filled entries

Comment: Sorry I just realised I copied that line from an old file... current version I use is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Please update though I dont think it will make any difference in this case

Comment: No problem, this didn't change anything as you mentioned. The latest screenshot on the original post seems to appear the same for filled or empty fields. I'm also a bit confused on the next steps from here; would I add `function2` to this success part?

Comment: you seem to be getting a 400 error from the server.... also I dont understand why does it show https://............../meta2sql when you are calling /runPythonFunc from ajax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219234/discussion-between-alwaysa-learner-and-henrik).

Answer (score 0):

take a try

```
async function function1() {
    form.action = "/runPythonFunc";
    await form.submit();
    function2('page2');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, had a go but got the error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: form is not defined at function1 at HTMLInputElement.onclick`. Looking into it